# subtracting similarly names columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

I have a data frame of 50 different animals (an example of cats and dogs is given below) and eight observations (an example of three is given below) and I would like to calculate the difference for each animal between each day ( _1, _2, _3) and day 0 (_0) as well as the day before (example, cats_3-cats_2).

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                'shelter cats_0 cats_1 cats_2 cats_3 dogs_0 dogs_1 dogs_2 dogs_3 
                 blue 4 4 2 1 3 4 8 3 
                 yellow 3 6 5 3 2 5 6 3 
                 green 2 7 3 2 8 4 2 2 
                 red 5 6 6 4 4 5 9 6 
                 orange 6 4 1 1 6 3 2 1' 
    header = TRUE )
```

The 'answer' below is just for cats. I do realize this will be a very wide table!!

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"shelter    cats_0  cats_1  cats_2  cats_3  cats_1-0    cats_2-0    cats_3-0    cats_2-1    cats_3-2
blue    4   4   2   1   0   -2  -3  -2  -1
yellow  3   6   5   3   3   2   0   -1  -2
green   2   7   3   2   5   1   0   -4  -1
red 5   6   6   4   1   1   -1  0   -2
orange  6   4   1   1   -2  -5  -5  -3  0",
header = TRUE
)
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I've played around with grep and an object with the names of the animals and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest code, but no dependencies and is fine if you really have < 10 each:

```
new_cats <- df[,grep("cats_[1-9]$", colnames(df), value=TRUE)] - df[,"cats_0"] 
new_dogs <- df[,grep("dogs_[1-9]$", colnames(df), value=TRUE)] - df[,"dogs_0"]

df <- cbind.data.frame(df, setNames(new_cats, sprintf("%s_0", colnames(new_cats))))
df <- cbind(df, setNames(new_dogs, sprintf("%s_0", colnames(new_dogs))))
```